# How to make an SMS notification to my phone with Arduino Uno?

Tags: arduino-uno

I am planning to make an SMS notification to my phone with Arduino Uno via a push of a button.

I have an Arduino Uno C520A Embedded System. Is it possible to do so with this model ? If yes, which WIFI module should I get ?

I just want to make an API request to the web through the push of a button.

Comment: You're going to need a GSM module and working simcard.

Comment: Check the specific devices datasheet for the (usually serial AT) commands.

Comment: + there are 100's of tutorials, just check them out on YouTube/blogs. Search for: Arduino send SMS.

Comment: How is the SMS notification related to the WiFi API requests?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible if your provider has a sms gateway e-mail-address. Just google which it is for your provider (e.g. number@tmomail.net for T-Mobile (US)). And there should be a lot of tutorial about how to send an email with an arduino.

Every wifi-module with arduino support will work if your WiFi is a standart 3.6Ghz. And yes it should work with any arduino compatible microcontroller.

Answer (score 1):

Arduino uno is only the processor, you will need a Ethernet shield or Wifi shield to connect to the internet.
I would suggest Ethernet as it is less pain to configure and no drop of connection.

Then you will need to buy a sms gateway, [this one](http://www.smsglobal.com/http-api/) looks pretty cool as they have good http api.

By using the Arduino Ethernet sample, you will need to send a http request to the server when the button has been pressed.